# php move_uploaded_file() permission of copied file

Tags: php, windows

I'm using move_uploaded_file() to move an uploaded file (picture) into a directory.
It works and the file is in the location but when I open it, I see the message Windows viewer can't open this picture because you don't have the correct permissions to access the file.

I have full access for the folder. I can manually copy/ paste/ delete from that folder, I copied the file manually and there was no problem.

[image]

It is just when I use move_uploaded_file() and try to open it manually (Goto file > open) I get the problem. When I access it through the browser, it opens with no problem `http://localhost/photos/kickoff.jpg`

I tried with both of the following ways when I set the directory
    
`//$dirnew = 'C:\Users\Amar\testweb\MyWeb\magazine\photos';`
    `$dirnew = '../magazine/photos/';`

I have tried now with 
`copy($_FILES[ 'fileToUpload'][ 'tmp_name' ],$dirnew . '/' . $_FILES[ 'fileToUpload'][ 'name' ]);`
 and this works. I can open the file uploaded in the same folder that I had permission issues using php move_uploaded_file().

The issue seems to be that the user is not added in permissions. So when I manually add the user, the file is ok.

[image]

Is there a way to include the user with move_uploaded_file()? No issue when using php copy as mentioned above.

Comment: what permissions does it have?

Comment: have you checked the permission of the folder if it is set to `0777` or `777`?

Comment: I just edited the post to show the permission. Both the same for folder and file

Comment: The absolute or relative path has definitely no impact on the permissions. You just simply need to give those files the read permission for the user you use to open them. Or to open them using the user in the Administrators group.

Comment: I only have one user on this machine that I am using and that user has full access and is part of administrator group. With the same user I also performed copy and paste into the same folder manually and it worked no problem

Comment: In the file properties (not permissions or security), does the uploaded image have the "This file came from another computer and may be blocked" flag set?

Comment: No it doesnt, I just looked at the permissions, Only system and Administrator is added and not the user when using move_uploaded_file(). I just added the user manually and I can open the picture. So how would I add a user when using move_uploaded_file() if that makes sense.

Comment: A permission error on windows.. thats something unexpected.

Comment: **For those using PHP on Windows and IIS, you SHOULD set the "upload_tmp_dir" value in php.ini to some directory around where your websites directory is, create that directory, and then set the same permissions on it that you have set for your websites directory. Otherwise, when you upload a file and it goes into C:\WINDOWS\Temp, then you move it to your website directory, its permissions will NOT be set correctly. This will cause you problems if you then want to manipulate that file with something like ImageMagick's convert utility.** ==> Note from php.net

Comment: @Xatenev The copy function (see above) uses the same tmp file and directory and the permissions are set when I use it. Same process tmp > website dir. It's just when using move_uploaded_file() its not added. So is this not an error with move_uploaded_file()?

Comment: @Amar Its probably an error with move_uploaded_file() and your webserver in combination. Anyways that doesn't help you saying "its an error with move_uploaded_file()" if you want your problem solved.